# Slow speed when downloading or sending files via Samba

Tags: linux, samba

I have a mini PC to which an SSD is connected via USB 3.0. Its speed is approximately 100-200 MBps. But if I upload or send files via Samba, the speed drops to 40 mbps. What is the problem? I use Linux both on a mini PC and on the main one.
I am using orange pi 3 LTS for samba host
there is a gigabit connection between a pc and a mini pc

Comment: Can you edit your post to be more specific with your units, so we know when you're talking about mebi (2^20) vs. mega (10^6), and bytes vs. bits?

Comment: What kind of “mini PC” are we talking about? A _PC_? Or maybe a single-board computer like a Raspberry Pi? Name the exact make and model and we can check its specifications.

Answer (score 0):

During network file transfer the following components are involved:

- filesystem(s) FS driver and USB device speed (in your particular case)
- network speed
- application layer for processing data on both server and client

**Filesystem**
depends on your distro `fio` or low level `dd` please google it there are plenty of example for usage.
Mine command is `fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=fiotest --filename=DISK_PATH/testfio --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=2G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75`

Please keep in mind on flag `--direct=1` for some systems this affecting the speed cause it is disabling caching etc, try with and without.
Don't forget to specify your path.
Consider testing client side as well.

**Network** speed you can use iperf or operf3 on both parties:
For server run `iperf -s` and for client `iperf -c <server IP addr>`

Last is **application** layer – Samba

For Samba you can use local connection in the order to read/write data from port. I mean bind share locally and try to read/write from or to the server in order to get access.
Please keep in mind that Samba can have plenty of parameters to adjust for proper functioning. For instance this thread, googled, https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/12986-tunning-samba-for-more-speed/ or many others.

Mine plan would be to investigate all parts of the flow before start investigating Samba, when all are settled – proceed with Samba investigation and tuning. Hope this will help.